# Simple Media Player in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a media player without `MediaPlayer` class, just a very basic VideoView which selects a file from device and plays it. But I am receiving an error

> Can't play this video.

Here's my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoPlayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        videoPlayer = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 7:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();
                    Toast.makeText(this, PathHolder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(PathHolder));
                    videoPlayer.requestFocus();
                    videoPlayer.start();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="318dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="716dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what logcat shows (i guess this contains the error):

> 2020-08-09 12:55:37.585 21894-21894/com.phantom.player W/MediaPlayer:
> Couldn't open /document/primary:WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
> Video/VID-20191031-WA0041.mp4
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /document/primary:WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp
> Video/VID-20191031-WA0041.mp4
> at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1680)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1510)
> at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1427)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.attemptDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1149)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1121)
> at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1145)
> at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:412)
> at android.widget.VideoView.access$2200(VideoView.java:83)
> at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:694)
> at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:926)
> at android.view.SurfaceView.windowStopped(SurfaceView.java:315)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setWindowStopped(ViewRootImpl.java:1973)
> at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.setStoppedState(WindowManagerGlobal.java:709)
> at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:8039)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:5007)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:268)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2080)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7807)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)

I am not used to content provider.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand what was the problem.But it was solved when I changed `onActivityResult` to

```
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 7:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    videoPlayer.setVideoURI(data.getData());
                    videoPlayer.requestFocus();
                    videoPlayer.start();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set orientation with object of video player

```
case 7:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(this, PathHolder, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                videoPlayer.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(PathHolder));
                videoPlayer.requestFocus();
                videoPlayer.start();
            }
```